# Synchronizing loading js files with ajax calls and loading js files with <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-events

core.js:

```
var core = 
{
    all:{},
    load: function(jsUrl)
    {
        $.ajaxStup({async, false});
        $.getScript(jsUrl);
    },
    init: function ()
    {

        $.getJSON('someurl', function(data)
        {
            for(key in this.all)
                alert(key);

        });
     },
     here: function(who)
     {
         this.all[who.name] = who;
     }
};
$(document).ready(function()
{
    core.init();
});
```

---

me.js

```
(function()
{
    core.here({name:"me", foo:"bar"});
})();
```

---

---

CASE 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    core.load("/me.js");
</script>
```

---

CASE 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/me.js"></script>
```

---

The problem is that for case 1 I get an alert, as I should , but for case 2, no alert...

So the question is: there is a load event for the `<script>` tag? Qhat can I use to synchronize the files to work on case 2 (while debugging in IE8, I noticed that using a breakpoint solves the problem)? Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: I'm looking at this and the document.ready should fire once the browser has all the Javascript so me.js & core.here should have loaded and run... thus filling 'all' and firing your alert().  

But from a code design standpoint it may be strange to just call init on document load. Why not just call it after you load .here like thats a constructor. So have that call it or call it after to push / upload ?

Comment: @Ryan Doom Indeed, document.ready is there only to point out that I`ve tried some (a lot... of) things... I would expect the 'here' function to be called at that point, because document.ready, as you said, is triggered once the browser has all the <script> tags resolved(loaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why CASE 1 happened to work for you, but your problem seems to lie here:

```
$.getJSON('someurl', function(data)
{
    alert(core === this); // <----- false, 'this' refers to the function's scope
    for(key in this.all)
        alert(key);
});
```

**"this" in javascript isn't the same as "this" in C++ or Java**

The problem is that `function(data){...}` creates a closure (with a new this).  So, inside that function, `this` no longer refers to `core`, it refers to the scope of the context from which it was called (somewhere inside jQuery in this case). You can fix it by *protecting* `this` with a new variable, like so.

```
var self = this;
$.getJSON('someurl', function(data) {
    for(var key in self.all){
        alert(key);
    }
});
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword) can point you in the right direction for demystifying the `this` keyword in javascript.